# Можно ли совместить два flutter приложения в одно?

Tags: android, flutter

Имеются два рабочих приложения на flutter. Можно ли объединить их в один проект? К примеру первое приложение будет главным, а второе - будет как новая страница в приложении. И как это сделать максимально безболезненно. Вопрос возможно глуповат, я новичок в программировании

Подскажите пожалуйста с чего нужно начать и как это реализовать

Comment: [Это?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65801995/combining-multiple-different-flutter-projects)